# Regex that's appending lines to the end of Replace()

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a dynamic code writer, and I'm working on a function that writes the XML documentation. All is well, except the function that formats the documentation is adding to the end undesirably, and I also need it to break on punctuation marks.

Current formatting function:

```
public static String FormatForXmlDocumentation(String xmlLine, Int32 spacing, 
  Int32 length = 120)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlLine))
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@".{0," + length.ToString() + "}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        return regex.Replace(xmlLine, "$0\r\n" + string.Empty.PadRight(spacing) + "/// ");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Test code ("!" to indicate end):

```
Console.WriteLine(RenderForCode.FormatForXmlDocumentation(
@"Data info: Type: <see cref=""System.Nullable`1[System.Double]""/>; Nullable: false; Default: 101.23d; Low: 100d; High: 200d", 4, 40
) + "!");
```

Current output:

```
Data info: Type: <see cref="System.Nulla
    /// ble`1[System.Double]"/>; Nullable: false
    /// ; Default: 101.23d; Low: 100d; High: 200
    /// d
    /// 
    /// !
```

Desired output:

```
Data info: Type: <see cref="System.
    /// Nullable`1[System.Double]"/>; Nullable: 
    /// false; Default: 101.23d; Low: 100d; 
    /// High: 200d!
```

Note that the calling function will handle the prefix for the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the regex:

```
@"\b.{0," + length.ToString() + @"}(?:(?!:)\b|$)"
```

The `\b` ensures words aren't split in the middle and `$` provides for the last line.

Comment: This also avoids splitting on things like `Nullable:` to `Nullable\r\n:`, but if there's more things like that, add them to the negative lookahead in a character class.

Comment: thanks, but this isn't actually splitting the input, and is still adding 2 lines to the end.

Comment: var regex = new Regex(@"\b.{0," + length.ToString() + "}(?:(?!:)\b|$)");
return regex.Replace(xmlLine, "$0\r\n" + string.Empty.PadRight(spacing) + "/// ");

Comment: I mean that with this regex (as I pasted the code in my prev comment), my input comes out as one long line, followed by 2 blank lines. No matter what length I state, I'm getting 1 long line. Could you paste your whole code please.

Comment: @IanC I don't know much C#, but would be going forward quickly if I knew how to join the results of a `Regex.Matches` through `string.Join` or something similar. For the one liner, I forgot to mention you need to add `@` to the second string like so: `@"}(?:(?!:)\b|$)"`.

Comment: I don't know about using join against the regex, so here's what I worked out. A bit messy, but it works: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlLine))
{
    string prefix = "/// ".PadLeft(4 + spacing);
    var regex = new Regex(@"\b.{0," + length.ToString() + @"}(?:(?!:)\b|$)");
    string result = regex.Replace(xmlLine, "$0\r\n" + prefix);
    result = result.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
    return (result.EndsWith(prefix)) ? result.Substring(0, result.Length - prefix.Length) : result;
}

Comment: @IanC Oh, okay. I can't say I understand everything that's happening, but I'm glad your code works now :)